# Are there Ijen Crater tours from Bali that finish at Yogyakarta?

Tags: planning, tours, routes, indonesia, guides

I can see tours *starting* at Yogya but I cannot find anything that starts at Bali and finishes at Yogya.

The plan is to start at Bali, visit the Ijen Crater, visit Mt. Bromo (not a deal breaker if not included) and finish in Yogya before then heading back to Bali.

I am looking for tours that at least take us up to Yogya.

Alternatively, is it fairly easy to make our own way from Ijen Crater to Yogya?